# send multiple binary files to server - codename one

Tags: post, binary, codenameone

I'm using Codename One to upload photos to a server. I'm using a multipart request to actually upload the file as binary using the adddata method. How can i send two or three binary files in one single post.

Answer (score 0):

Add data accepts a name:

```
addData(String name, byte[] data, String mimeType) 
addData(String name, String filePath, String mimeType)
addData(String name, InputStream data, long dataSize, String mimeType)
```

In all its variants. You can upload multiple files by calling this method multiple times.